Does a British Italian dual national need to carry both passports when traveling from Italy to the UK?
I am a dual national from birth of both Britain and Italy. Up till now I've never had any issues entering the UK on my Italian passport. But today they stopped me saying I needed to prove I'm British. I had a photo of an old British passport that I've not renewed because the Italian passport is more powerful and so I only used that one to travel. They let me through, but border force said to me I need to prove in some way I am British next time.
I think it's crazy to have to buy a UK passport just for the purpose of entering my own country. Is there another way to add perhaps to the Italian passport that I'm British?

It's not unheard of that countries demand their citizens use their passports to enter/leave. Most countries that allow dual citizenship - don't recognize it. In the country of your citizenship you're only considered citizen of that one country regardless of your other citizenships.

Why did you need to prove you are British? Italian citizens can travel to the UK without needing a visa for up to six months - at least until sometime next year when you'd need to get an ETA. I have travelled several times on my German passport since my UK passport expired without issue.

You can't buy a passport because it "remains the property of his majesty's government."  You pay an application fee, and if the application is successful they issue a passport, but you don't own it.

@JackAidley perhaps aiphos resides in the UK.

@JackAidley an Italian citizen can visit the UK. They cannot live or work in the UK unless they have a relevant visa or residence permit… or are actually a British citizen. If OP has already spent a lot of time in the UK over the last year, that would indeed trigger more questions from the Border Force and a request for relevant evidence.

@jcaron Yes, obviously. That's why I am asking the question.

"I needed to prove I'm British" — Does Britain not issue a citizenship card when one is naturalized? I've never needed to, but in your situation I'd carry my British passport and my Canadian citizenship card (which never expires so doesn't require renewal fees).

@RayButterworth Britain does not have citizenship cards or any similar identity document than the passport (some exceptions exist, e.g the NI electoral identity card, but that's the general picture).

@RayButterworth if the UK is anything like the US, they issue a naturalization certificate on a piece of paper that is difficult and expensive to replace.  Since the UK no longer has national ID cards, the most convenient and affordable evidence of British citizenship is the passport.

@RayButterworth Does Britain not issue a citizenship card when one is naturalized? Almost the opposite is true. The only people in the UK who have ID cards are people who are not citizens, who may hold biometric residence permits–but in fact these are being phased out, and from next year, neither citizens nor non citizens will have ID cards.


They let me through, but border force said to me I need to prove in some way I am British next time.

Only a British passport or 'certificate of entitlement' is legally defined as conclusive for the purpose of establishing British citizenship when entering the UK.

Is there another way to add perhaps to the Italian passport that I'm British?

Unfortunately it is more expensive than a passport. You can apply for a 'certificate of entitlement', to go in your Italian passport, but this costs £550.
https://www.gov.uk/right-of-abode/apply-for-a-certificate-of-entitlement
Additionally, the Home Office has given a hint that they may be developing an electronic solution to this issue in their newest eVisa FAQ.

British passport holders and Irish citizens, including those who previously held an immigration status but have since acquired British citizenship, do not need to do anything. British citizens who do not have a British passport because they are dual nationals (excluding Irish passport holders) may need to take action in future regarding how they prove their right of abode. Updates on this will be provided in due course.

https://homeofficemedia.blog.gov.uk/2024/10/02/media-factsheet-evisas-2/
For now, I'd suggest renewing your passport is the best option. £88.50 for a 10 year passport is not that bad a deal, in my opinion.

It's certainly a much better deal than £550 for a certificate of entitlement!

The certificate of entitlement is not really a proof of UK citizenship. It's only a way to prove one has "right of abode" in the UK (i.e. can live and work there without any limits, like a UK citizen would) when one is not a British citizen. It's destined for some citizens of the Commonwealth who are (now adult, aged 42+) children of UK-born British citizens (conditions apply). I'm not even sure they would grant one to an actual British citizen.

@jcaron It is still sufficient for entry to the UK, since all UK citizens have right of abode. Yes, they can be granted to citizens, as long as they do not hold a valid passport. And it is particularly helpful for British citizens who have children abroad and don't want the multi-month wait for a first British passport to bring their newborn to the UK. See guidance: https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/6490650b5f7bb7000c7fad3a/Guide_ROA_-_Jun_2023.pdf

@jcaron the border force doesn't really need proof of British citizenship per se; they need proof of the right of abode.  They told aiphos that it was necessary to prove British citizenship because aiphos's right of abode stems from British citizenship.

@MJeffryes Definitely would be enough to enter the UK, no contest on that. However in the case of a newborn: (a) the newborn would need to have another citizenship and (b) the newborn would need to have a passport from their other citizenship. And I wonder how long it takes to get that certificate of entitlement... They say the decision is usually given within 8 weeks, does it really take that long to get a passport?

Letting your own citizens pay for documentation that is mandatory is waylaying, in my opinion. Of course all countries do it, but I find it ... wrong.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica I'm inclined to agree, but the UK does not require its citizens to have a passport nor any other particular document.  A passport is arguably required in certain circumstances, which is not the same thing as being absolutely mandatory.  In that respect it is like a driver's license.

@jcaron Yes, in many cases it is quicker to get a foreign passport and the certificate than it is to get a UK passport. In some countries it can take over 6 months for a first UK passport.

This has happened as a result of Brexit: with only an Italian passport you are considered to be just an Italian citizen and you are no longer allowed to live and work in the UK without a relevant visa or permit, so it’s legitimate they ask for proof of UK citizenship.
You write:

I think it's crazy to have to buy a UK passport just for the purpose of entering my own country.

Well, you need some way to actually prove that you are. Otherwise anybody can just tell them “hey let me in I’m British, I swear”.
Italy is not competent to state whether you are British or not, and the UK won’t issue visas to their own citizens, so no, there’s nothing which can be done in your Italian passport for that purpose. By far the simplest way is to have a UK passport.
In other countries you could have used a national ID card, but that doesn’t exist in the UK.

There actually is something that can be done with an Italian passport to prove the traveller’s right of abode in the UK. A certificate of entitlement can be endorsed in the Italian passport.

Of course they can ask someone with Italian passport whether they have either a British passport or a visa for Italian citizens. Most dual citizens won’t have this visa (it might even be impossible to get since it isn’t needed)

@gnasher729 the reason for the existence of the certificate of entitlement is precisely because the UK does not issue visas to British citizens.  The reason for the excessively high cost of the certificate of entitlement is a mystery to me.

@phoog See my comment on MJeffryes's answer. Not quite what a certificate of entitlement is (from what I understand).

@jcaron a certificate of entitlement is a visa-like sticker that goes in a foreign passport to serve as proof that the bearer has right of abode in the UK, which all British citizens have.  A British citizen who does not want a British passport can get a certificate of entitlement instead.  What part of this is inconsistent with your understanding?

... a British citizen who does not want a British passport and holds a foreign passport...

As a British citizen you have nothing to fear from the UK Border Force
You write...

They let me through, but border force said to me I need to prove in some way I am British next time.

The border force has ~zero power over you as a British citizen. They can't ban you from your own country - and even if such a "ban" was issued, it would have no legal effect whatsoever. They can hold you up for secondary inspection but no matter how annoyed they are about your lack of British passport, there's not much they can do about it other than grumble and then let you through.
From April 2nd 2025 Italian citizens will be required to pre-apply for Electronic Travel Authorization beefore flying to the UK, however I doubt you'd be prevented from doing so using your Italian passport. It would be an extra hassle but possibly still cheaper than bothering to get a British passport.
Would I personally go get a British passport? Yes, definitely.
Is it absolutely necessary? Nope, you can keep doing what you do, it is your legal right to do so.

I wish Indian border agents are similar. Amount of questions they ask to let me in my own country is ridiculous.

What guarantee do you have that you will be treated as British if you have no proof that you are? And even if you are eventually able to prove it, they can hold you in a cell until you do so.

Also, the Border Force absolutely have power over British citizens which they are able to use for matters of customs and excise as well as counter-terrorism.

"there's not much they can do about it other than grumble and then let you through": this is only true to the extent that they believe the claim of British citizenship.  It's not enough simply to be a British citizen; you have to be able to convince them that you are.  If they're saying that OP needs to be able to prove this, then at some point they could well start making it more difficult, for example by being (or pretending to be) more skeptical of whatever evidence is actually presented.

@JackAidley we have a first-hand report about the Heathrow detention center: it's a bit unpleasant but not an actual prison and doesn't count as an "arrest". Even if you were to be deported, the Border Force cannot place a ban on you and you could just hop over the very next day, in addition to filing a complaint against the officers involved. Could make for a nice news story too and could help revamp the operations at the border if it happens. Honestly if I was a British citizen I'd consider it a fun adventure to visit it.

@phoog eh, if you're an experienced traveler who doesn't care much about a potential border delay you have nothing to fear from the Border Force. They can delay your journey a bit but at the end of the day OP is not violating any laws by traveling with an Italian passport. If you're a citizen the government works for you, not the other way around, though of course you should always be polite and courteous.

@JonathanReez: I think the number of people who would consider being held in a cell "a fun adventure" is relatively small, even on top of the inconvenience and potential cost of having your arrival delayed by hours.

"if you're an experienced traveler who doesn't care much about a potential border delay you have nothing to fear from the Border Force": in my experience, the more experienced the traveler, the greater the concern about potential border delay. If you cross a border a couple of times a year, an hour or two is unpleasant but manageable. If you do it a few times a week, it's another matter entirely. "If you're a citizen the government works for you": the government serves all citizens collectively, and that sometimes means treating certain citizens (especially suspected noncitizens) unpleasantly.

@phoog OP has been warned about the possible delays. If they accept those, then it’s their decision. I just wanted to point out that “grumblings” from the Border Force can be safely ignored by citizens.
